How can I change the EC2 launch template used by an Elastic Beanstalk environment?
I edited the launch template associated with one of my environments, which created a new version. But then when I added a new instance to the environment, it still used the old version.
Do I have to do something else to tell the environment to use the new version?
Thanks

I found the solution:
Find the Auto Scaling Group which is associated with your Elastic Beanstalk environment. The Scaling Group will have a name which includes the EB environment's ID.
Edit the Scaling Group and in the Launch Template section, set the "Version" to "Latest".
